# Hive External Table with Azure Blob Storage

Tags: hive, azure-storage

Is there a way to create a Hive external table using SerDe with location pointing to Azure Storage, organized in such a way that the data uses the fewest number of blobs. For example if insert 10000 records, I would like it to create just 100 page blobs with 100 line records each instead of maybe 10000 with 1 record each. I am de serializing from the blob, so fewer blobs will require lesser time.What would be the most optimal format in hive?

Answer (score 1):

First, there is a way to create a Hive external table using Serde with localtion pointing to Azure Blob Storage, but not directly, please see the section [`Create Hive database and tables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/machine-learning-data-science-move-hive-tables#a-namecreate-tablesacreate-hive-database-and-tables) like the HiveQL below.

```
create database if not exists <database name>;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE if not exists <database name>.<table name>
(
    field1 string,
    field2 int,
    field3 float,
    field4 double,
    ...,
    fieldN string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '<field separator>' lines terminated by '<line separator>'
STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '<storage location>' TBLPROPERTIES("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

And focus the below content for explaination `<storage location>`.

> **`<storage location>`**: the Azure storage location to save the data of Hive tables. If you do not specify LOCATION , the database and the tables are stored in hive/warehouse/ directory in the default container of the Hive cluster by default. If you want to specify the storage location, the storage location has to be within the default container for the database and tables. This location has to be referred as location relative to the default container of the cluster in the format of '`wasb:///<directory 1>/`' or '`wasb:///<directory 1>/<directory 2>/`', etc. After the query is executed, the relative directories are created within the default container.

So it means you can access Azure Blob Storage location on Hive via `wasb` protocol, which required `hadoop-azure` library that support Hadoop access HDFS on Azure Storage. If your Hive on Hadoop not deployed on Azure, you need to refer to the Hadoop offical document [`Hadoop Azure Support: Azure Blob Storage`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-azure/index.html) to configure it.

For using serde, it is depended on the file format you used, like for orc file format, the hql code using `OrcSerde` like below.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXSISTS <table name> (<column_name column_type>, ...)
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde' 
    STORED AS ORC 
    LOCATION '<orcfile path>'
```

For your second, the most optimal format is [`ORC File Format`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC) in Hive.